# Alter CSS applied by LESS Mixin when body class is present?

Tags: less

I have a LESS mixin. When I apply this to an element I want it be styled slightly differently if a body class is present.

This:

```
.mixin() {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}

.element {
  .mixin()
}

Outputs to this:

.element {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}

But I also want this to be outputted:

.body-class .element {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Oopss, sorry its me again. Are you meaning to say that you need both the rules for with body-class and without it to be part of same mixin?

Comment: Yes. I want to use the same mixin which will have a semantic name like page-heading. The same CSS will be used by 2 different sites. These have different body classes and I need one to have a different color than the other.

Comment: I have updated my [old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606726/alter-less-mixin-when-body-class-is-present/28606900#28606900) itself with a way because this is a small improvement on that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your mixin this way:

```
.mixin() {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;

  .body-class & {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```